# Does there exist an involutive orthonormal frame on the tangent bundle?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

Let $M$ be a smooth $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, and let $p \in M$.

Does there always exist an open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$, and an orthonormal frame $E_i$ over $U$, s.t $\text{span}\{ E_1,\dots,\hat E_i,\dots E_d\} $ is involutive for every $i$?

Does it help if we only require $\text{span}\{ E_1,\dots,\hat E_i,\dots E_d\} $ to be involutive for a single $i$?

Comment: For a single $i$, this is definitely doable. Take any local coordinate frame $\partial_{x_1}, \dots, \partial_{x_d}$ and perform the Gram-Schmidt procedure on it to get an orthonormal frame $E_1,\dots,E_d$. Since $\operatorname{span} \{ \partial_{x_1}, \dots, \partial_{x_{d-1}} \} = \operatorname{span} \{ E_1, \dots, E_{d-1} \}$, this distribution is involutive. The more general case seems less trivial - you can write it as a system of first order PDEs which is overdetermined if $n > 3$ but I'm not sure what are the compatibility conditions required for a solution and whether they always hold.

Comment: (I would guess not).

Comment: Thanks! you are right of course.  Can you write those PDE's you mentioned? (If it's long/cumbersome I will just find you at the campus:)